# Right Circular Cone Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A right circular cone has height $h$ and a base of radius $a$.  Choose the origin to be at the apex of the cone and the positive z axis to be the axis of symmetry of the cone.

$1)$Show that a point on the curved surface of the cone can be parametrised as $$r = z ( \frac{a}{h} \cos \phi e_x + \frac{a}{h} \sin \phi e_2 + e_z)$$

The next part then goes through a series of steps to calculate the volume of the cone:  Obtain $r \cdot dS$ on the surface and the base and thus find the volume by the divergence theorem.

However, the final question is:
Generalise your calculation to the case of a cone of height h whose (non circular) base is a plane surface of area A. Hints: Take origin at apex of cone and z axis perpendicular to base. The angle between the position vector and unit normal to the curved surface is $\pi/2$.

Attempt: I can do i), by comparing the given paramtrisation to the Cartesain form of a cone.  However, I am also interested in the actual derivation of the parametrisation.  I have tried to draw some triangles but I didn't manage to attain the result.

For generalisation, if the base is not a circle, then how can it possibly be a cone?

Many thanks.

Comment: It may be e.g. an elliptic cone such as $z=-\sqrt{3x^2+5y^2}.$

Comment: I see. I suppose I was thinking of bases like a square.

Comment: So if the angle between the position vector and the curved surface is always pi/2, then I don't need to bother about computing the surface integral $r \cdot dS$.  For the base, do I just assume that the only other possibility is that of an ellipse and do a parametrisation of an ellipse dotted into a unit normal along the z axis?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand how can it be that "the angle between the position vector and the curved surface is always pi/2", when the curved surface is a cone.

Comment: Rather, the angle between the position vector and the unit normal to the curved surface.

Comment: OK, now I see. But I have no ideas on how to answer your question.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway.  But I can assume that a cone can only comprise a base which is either circular or elliptical.  (i.e I cannot have a square based cone)? Would you be able to explain why  the angle between the position vector and the unit normal is always $\pi/2$? I tried to visualise it and I can't see why they would have to be perpendicular. Thanks.

Comment: As for the 1st question, from the Wikipedia: " a pyramid is technically a cone with a polygonal base." As for the 2nd my explanation is that the position vector (assuming the origin is at the apex of the cone) is tangent to the surface, or better, lies on the surface, because it coincides with a segment of the generatrix.

Comment: So a cone's base can be somewhat arbritary.  I'll have to think about the question a little bit more.  I understand now why the position vector is perpendicular to the unit normal. Thanks.